# The annotation @ApiResponses is disallowed for this location

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am getting below error:
**The annotation @ApiResponses is disallowed for this location**
We are using swagger2.2.0

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/example")
@ApiResponses(value = {  @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 204, message = "No Content"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad Request"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error")})
public class SomeController{

}
```

Do we have any option without upgrading swagger version?
**Please help..**

Answer (score 2):

this is because @ApiResponses annotation can be used only on method!

Below is an example snippet:

```
 @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Invalid ID supplied"),
 @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Pet not found") })
 public Response getPetById(...) {...}
```

Comment: That's not true. I upgraded swagger version to 2.9.0 and it accept at Class level. I have different problem though with 2.9.0.

Comment: @Mebin - I think make sense on method level in case of swagger version 2.2.0 but 2.9.0 on class level also you can provide. Thanks a lot for clue anyway. I am putting on method level without upgrading swagger version.

Comment: @Nishant. If so could you please mark Mirko's answer as useful. Thank you.

Comment: @Nishant https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations#apiresponse :)